# Why am i getting this error "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous" python

Tags: python

My dataframe df_reps look like this

```
        RepID  TermCnt 
0           1       12 
1           1        4 
2           1        3 
3           1        4 
4           1        2 
      ...      ...  ...
1116984  4999        3 
1116985  4999        2 
1116986  4999        1 
1116987  4999        2 
1116988  4999        1
```

I am trying to create a new column called Cat

using

```
df_reps["Cat"] = df_reps["TermCnt"] if df_reps["TermCnt"] < 3 else 99
```

but getting this error

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I checked this link

[Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

and it is seems there is a non logical if statement

but when I try this line

```
df_reps["TermCnt"] < 3
```

I get these values

```
df_reps["TermCnt"] < 3
Out[96]: 
0          False
1          False
2          False
3          False
4           True
 
1116984    False
1116985     True
1116986     True
1116987     True
1116988     True
Name: TermCnt, Length: 1116989, dtype: bool
```

which means the logical part is correct

any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) method:

```
df_reps["Cat"]=df_reps["TermCnt"].apply(lambda x:x if x < 3 else 99)
```

Now if you print `df_reps` you will get your desired output

Comment: WHen I expand the statement i get the same error  df_reps["Cat"]=df_reps["TermCnt"].apply(lambda x:x if x < 3 else df_reps["Perc25"] if x<=df_reps["Perc25"] else df_reps["Perc50"] if x<=df_reps["Perc50"] else df_reps["Perc75"] if x<=df_reps["Perc75"] else df_reps["Perc100"] )

Comment: i found the reason, it is actually because i am using df_reps["Perc25"]  instead of x["Perc25"]  etc.